# ArcGIS project raster produces incorrect vertical coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.6

[image]I have a DEM in UTM (meters) / NAVD88 (meters) and need to transform it to *State Plane (feet) / NAVD88 (feet)*. Unfortunately, I do not have the raster calculator in ArcGIS, so I have to use *Project Raster* and apply a vertical transformation. My xy coordinates are correct and the scale of my vertical coordinates is correct. Since they are both on the same datum (*NAVD88*) and only differ in scale, you'd think that the vertical transformation would be easy (just multiply the vertical values by ~3.28) and would work correctly. However, every time I apply this transformation, the vertical coordinates shift upwards by ~ 5' from their desired position . Any idea why this happens?

**Side note**: I have resolved this problem in QGIS, but would like to try to figure out why I am having trouble in ArcGIS as I would prefer to perform all of my GIS operations in ArcGIS. The attached image shows the default transformation which is applied (unnecessarily/erroneously) during the operation.

Comment: What did you do in QGIS that was successful?

Comment: Converted the projection, raster calculator to convert vertical coordinates (just multiplied by 3.28084), and then used the Whitebox Tools convertrasterformat tool to convert it to the format I need. I’m trying to figure I why it won’t work in ArcGIS though

Comment: Is the projected coordinate system used in QGIS the same as the one in Arc? I know between the two there can be some small differences. Another thing I would try would be to look at your environment settings for the raster https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/environment-settings-for-raster-data.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaphs you need to have a geocoder  within your other layers of your map? I know I have made a local locator when my coordinates are off.